# Python - Matplotlib responsive window without blocking

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I have a main thread which collects data in real time. When it receives some data it adds the data to a stack. The stack is then processed by another thread which writes the data to disk.

Now i also want this thread to plot some of the data (every minute or so). I really like Matplotlibs 3D scatter plot (you can rotate and zoom with the mouse etc.). Problem is, either the window is blocking, so my program doesn't continue, or, if I make it non-blocking, the window controls are unresponsive (no mouse rotation etc.). Is there a way I can have both? I tried doing the Matplotlib stuff in another thread, but then it complains it needs to be in the main thread (tried this with default QT4 and TkAgg backend).

File: plotter.py

```
import numpy as np 
from pylab import *
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import threading

class plotter:
    def showThread(self):
        plt.show()

    def __init__(self):
        print "plotter initializing"
    #    plt.ion() 
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax1 = Axes3D(fig)
        self.ax1 = ax1
        ax1.scatter([0],[0],[0])        
        ax1.set_xlim3d(0,512,30)
        ax1.set_ylim3d(0,256,30)
        ax1.set_zlim3d(0,20,5)
        plt.draw()
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.showThread)
        t.start()

    def plot(self,xlist,ylist,zlist):
        #This function updates the plot..
        self.ax1.scatter(xlist,ylist,zlist)        
        self.ax1.set_xlim3d(0,512,30)
        self.ax1.set_ylim3d(0,256,30)
        self.ax1.set_zlim3d(0,20,5) 
        plt.draw()
```

Error TkInter:

```
TclError: out of stack space (infinite loop?)
```

Error QT4 (gives more errors):

```
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt4.py", line 73, in mainloop
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
ValueError: signal only works in main thread
```

Comment: don't mix embedding with `pyplot`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391038/deleting-and-redrawing-matplotlib-animation/18391327#18391327 and http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt4.html